# npm error - Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

Tags: node.js, npm

i noticed the error when i tried to run npx create-react-app and since then i have been unable to use npm for anything. i have uninsatlled and reinstalled node severally yet same error keeps coming up.

the error:

```
 npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN logfile could not be created: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\DevSayae\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-07T07_54_40_928Z-debug-0.log'
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:353
      const err = new Error(
                  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\HP PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-inflight\inflight.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:353:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:566:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cacache\lib\util\fix-owner.js:7:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\HP PC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\promise-inflight\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'promise-inflight'
}
```

[npm log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8umSN.png)

Comment: Can you share your tsconfig?

Comment: oh ok i'm using js, react, though i have solved the problem thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve this problem by going into this path on my PC:

'C:\Users\HP PC\AppData\Roaming\npm',

deleted the npm folder and then uninsall node.js from my Pc, and finally re-installed node.js again. And after that everything works just fine

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem earlier and after searching for a solution I solved the problem by deleting the **node_modules** folder and then I run the following commands:

> npm update

and then

> npm install

after this, the app was still running without issues.